# How to print "Time" field in twig template

Tags: 8, theming, datetime

I have a [time field](https://www.drupal.org/project/time_field) in my content type. But when I entered time in the format 05:00 AM, I get a five digit timestamp eg. 18000 (for 05:00 AM).

When I print this using `node.field_time.value|date('h:i A')` it prints

> 10:30 AM

which is 05:30 Hrs extra than the entered one.
How do I'll get the correct time?

The default timezone is set to Kolkata which is +05:30 UTC. Is this something causing the problem?

Comment: By default, it considers the entered time as UTC. So when we render the time field, it appears with respect to the user's time zone. Maybe by using `drupal_get_user_timezone()`.

Comment: Yes, simply piping to the date format won’t take time zone into account as it’s just a value, as opposed to letting Drupal render a date value where it will do that.

Comment: I think when you install a field module you should also configure the field formatter of this module and then print the formatted output, for example with `{{ content.field_time }}`.

Comment: @Kevin I use `node.field_time.value|date('h:i A', 'UTC')` and get the desired output. But have doubt if it is a correct way or not.

Comment: @4k4 unfortunately there is no configuration available for this module.

Comment: You could create a field formatter though. Custom field types may not be covered by general formatters (like Dates) and need to have it plugged in.

Comment: @Kevin, the module has a field formatter https://cgit.drupalcode.org/time_field/tree/src/Plugin/Field/FieldFormatter/TimeFormatter.php. Hashmat, configure the field formatter in Manage Display of the content type where you've added the field.

Comment: @4k4 the formatter is there but, it is not helpful to output the same time (without a +05:30 Hrs). Though I used `'UTC'` to declare the timezone, in my twig template to print the same time as I entered.

Comment: @Hashmat, this depends on how the module stores data entered in the field widget and outputs it in the field formatter. If this doesn't produce the correct time submit an issue in the issue queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, it considers the entered time as UTC. So when we render the value of the time field, it prints the value according to the user's timezone.

I used below code to print the same value as entered in the backend

`node.field_time.value|date('h:i A', 'UTC')`

or we can also use `false` instead of `UTC` to get the same output without setting any time zone.